# MySQL: connection refused...coudn't find mysqld.service

Tags: linux, rhel, yum, mysql

I am trying to install MySQL onto a Fedora 14 VM. I successfully installed it using

```
yum install mysql mysql-server
```

after which I tried to start it with

```
systemctl start mysqld.service
```

which returned the message

```
Failed to get D-Bus connection: Failed to connect to socket /org/freedesktop/systemd1/private: Connection refused
```

I also tried

```
systemctl enable mysqld.servie
```

which returned "Couldn't find mysqld.service."
Can someone please tell me how I can fix this and start the server?

Comment: what happens if you try with: service mysqld start ?

Comment: That did it! Thank you! You should post it as an answer so I can mark it as the best one haha

Comment: It is ok. I am glad it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You're expecting systemd to work on a version of Fedora that pre-dates the full introduction of systemd into Fedora.  That came in Fedora **15**.  Fedora 14 had but a "feature preview" that wasn't enabled straight out of the box.  Out of the box, Fedora 14 ran upstart, so you'll have to make sure that you installed an upstart job definition for mysqld and start it with [upstart's `initctl start` command](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#start).  Failing that, you can use a System 5 `rc` script for mysqld with upstart's backwards compatibility mechanisms.

Or you could stick with the systemd way of doing things that you obviously *know*, and execute [all of the magic incantations for getting that "feature preview" limping along](http://lwn.net/Articles/401856/).  Or you could simply use a newer Fedora.  ☺